# Как на php вывести рандомно числа,не повторяющие друг друга?

Tags: php

дано 100 чисел,необходимо вывести 10 случайных чисел из 100 при условии чтобы числа не повторялись

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-нить так можно

```
$nums = range(1,100);
shuffle($nums);
$result = array_slice($nums, 0, 10);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Перетасуй числа в исходном массиве по любому алгоритму  тасования (например тасование фишера — йетса)
2. Возьми 10 чисел начиная с произвольного индекса, хоть с самого начала

---

Тасование:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); ++$i) {
    $r = rand(0, $i);
    $tmp = $arr[$i];
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$r];
    $arr[$r] = $tmp;  
}
```